# Python for loop is only executing the first element in a string and not iterating through the rest of the string

Tags: python-3.x

I am working on a school project. I want my for loop to loop through the string and convert each letter to Braille but it is only converting the first element of the string.

Code:

```py
def word_to_braille(word):

    '''(str) -> str
    Given a string with no spaces and no newlines, convert to a Braille o-string.
    Put two newlines in between every Braille cell.
    The print_ostrint function we use in the doctest is to make the output more readable.

    Remember digits should have NUMBER before them.
    Capital letters should have CAPITAL before them unless...
        ...all of the variable "word" is capital letters and there are at least two capital letters.**
        In that case: put CAPITAL twice at the front instead.
        Hint: remember the helper function is_all_caps.
    >>> print_ostring(word_to_braille('CHAT'))
    .o .o oo o. o. .o
    .. .. .. oo .. oo
    .o .o .. .. .. o.
    '''
    if is_all_caps(word):
        for i in word:
            return ('.o\n..\n.o\n\n' + '.o\n..\n.o\n\n') + char_to_braille(i)
```

Expected:

```
.o .o oo o. o. .o
.. .. .. oo .. oo
.o .o .. .. .. o.
```

Output:

```
.o .o oo
.. .. ..
.o .o ..
```

The helper functions are defined elsewhere but they pass the tests without issues. 
Sorry if the formatting of the question is not appropriate, it's my first question on this website:)

Comment: `return` will exit the function immediately. You're going to have to find some other way of building the string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the "return" out of the loop because it is used to end the function run and return a value.

Instead, you should append the results of each iteration to a variable and then return the variable after the loop completes.